# PySpark Dataframe transform columns into rows

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe

```
REC_DATA = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
      ('exercise', 'fiber', 'rice', 'male'),
      ('exercise', 'rice', 'fiber', 'female'),
      ('exercise', 'water', 'fiber', 'male'),
      ('exercise', 'rice', 'exercise', 'female'),
    ], 
      StructType(
        [
            StructField("1_rec", StringType(), False),
            StructField("2_rec", StringType(), False),
            StructField("3_rec", StringType(), False),
            StructField("sex", StringType(), True),
        ]
    )
)
```

| 1_rec | 2_rec | 3_rec | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| exercise | fiber | rice | male |
| exercise | rice | fiber | female |
| exercise | water | fiber | male |
| water | rice | exercise | female |

And I'm trying to group these rows into a new column, transforming the columns 1_rec, 2_rec, 3_rec into rows, and add a new column with the quantity, the output should be like that:

| Position | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_rec | exercise | 3 |
| 1_rec | water | 1 |
| 2_rec | water | 1 |
| 2_rec | rice | 2 |
| 2_rec | fiber | 1 |
| 3_rec | rice | 1 |
| 3_rec | fiber | 2 |
| 3_rec | exercise | 1 |

I had tried to do a Crosstab but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stack` to kind of unpivot columns then group them by *position* and *name*

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

REC_DATA = (REC_DATA
            .selectExpr("stack(3, '1_rec', 1_rec, '2_rec', 2_rec, '3_rec', 3_rec) (position, name)")
            .groupBy('position', 'name')
            .agg(F.count("*").alias('count')))
REC_DATA.show()

+--------+--------+-----+
|position|    name|count|
+--------+--------+-----+
|   1_rec|   water|    1|
|   2_rec|    rice|    2|
|   3_rec|exercise|    1|
|   3_rec|   fiber|    2|
|   2_rec|   water|    1|
|   3_rec|    rice|    1|
|   1_rec|exercise|    3|
|   2_rec|   fiber|    1|
+--------+--------+-----+
```